# Fontsize equal in all platform

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.ios, xamarin.android, xamarin.forms

I want font size in all platform uniform, as the default font size in ios and android have different values for micro, small, medium and large.For example defualt fontsize in ios is 17 while in android it is 15  FontSize medium in ios is 17, while in android it is 18. How to make it uniform for all platforms in xamarin.forms?

Comment: Different sizes is mentioned in Page number 79 of this link https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/xamarin-forms/creating-mobile-apps-xamarin-forms/preview-2/ xamarin.forms ebook by xamarin.

Comment: xyzWty, Being an ebook, its page numbers have changed as it was enhanced. Are you referring to "Chapter 5: Dealing with sizes"?

Comment: @ToolmakerSteve yes.

Answer (score 3):

This worked for me (Xamarin.Forms 2.3.3.175):

**In app.xaml:**

```
 <ResourceDictionary>
 <OnPlatform x:Key="SmallTextSize" x:TypeArguments="x:Double" 
 iOS="12.0" Android="12.0" WinPhone="14.0" />

 <Style TargetType="MyCustomLabel">
 <Setter Property="TextColor" Value="#3399FF" />
 <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="{DynamicResource SmallTextSize}"/>
 </Style>
</ResourceDictionary>
```

**In view.xaml:**

```
<StackLayout>
  <c:MyCustomLabel Text="{Binding TextField1}"/>
  <c:MyCustomLabel Text="{Binding TextField2}" 
   FontAttributes="Bold"/>
 </StackLayout>
```

The first "MyCustomLabel" will be assigned FontSize=SmallTextSize and TextColor from the Style, the second "MyCustomLabel" will be assigned FontAttributes=Bold, but it will keep the FontSize=SmallTextSize assigned by the Style.

If you are working with x:TypeArguments="Font" as suggested above, overwriting the FontAttributes will also reset the FontSize assigned in the Style.

https://jfarrell.net/2015/02/07/platform-specific-styling-with-xamarin-forms/

Comment: in ios platform , there is huge difference in fontsizes how to make it dynamic for diferent screensize? for example in iphone 5,5s fontsize medium looks large while in iphone 6,6s fontsize mediuam looks normal size. how to make it device size specific?

Answer (score 1):

You have to calculate screen height and width based on that give Label font size

The below code will help to design mobile screens on the basis of mobile screen height and width.

Design based on this it will fit all mobile resolutions.

**PCL:**

**App.cs**

```
public class App : Application
{                     
public static int screenHeight, screenWidth;

public App()
{           
    MainPage = new UserLogin();
    //The root page of your application         
}

protected override void OnStart()
{
     // Handle when your app starts
}

protected override void OnSleep()
{
    // Handle when your app sleeps
}

protected override void OnResume()
{
    // Handle when your app resumes
  }
}
```

**Xamarin.Android:**

MainActivity.cs

#region For screen Height & Width

```
    var pixels = Resources.DisplayMetrics.WidthPixels;
    var scale = Resources.DisplayMetrics.Density;

    var dps = (double)((pixels - 0.5f) / scale);

    var ScreenWidth = (int)dps;

    App.screenWidth = ScreenWidth;

    //RequestedOrientation = ScreenOrientation.Portrait;

    pixels = Resources.DisplayMetrics.HeightPixels;
    dps = (double)((pixels - 0.5f) / scale);

    var ScreenHeight = (int)dps;
    App.screenHeight = ScreenHeight;
```

## endregion

**Xamarin.iOS**

**AppDelegate.cs**

```
#region For Screen Height & Width

  App.screenWidth = (int)UIScreen.MainScreen.Bounds.Width;
      App.screenHeight = (int)UIScreen.MainScreen.Bounds.Height;
```

#endregion

**PCL**

If you used MVVM pattern you have to get these ScreeenHeight and ScreenWidth in ViewModel Then give height and widths for your Views and Layouts.

```
         // The below two lines will use to get the MOBILE SCREEN HEIGHT && WIDTH in ViewModel
          int heightScreen=App.screenHeight;
          int widthScreen=App.screenHeigh
```

**XAML Design:**

**UserLogin.xaml**

```
   <ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms" xmlns:local="clr-
  SreenSizeDemo;assembly=SreenSizeDemo" xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml" 
   x:Class="SreenSizeDemo.UserLogin">
  <StackLayout>
   <Label x:Name="lblTitle" HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand"/>
   <Image x:Name="imgProfile"  Source="Logo.png" />
  <StackLayout>
  <ContentPage>
```

**UserLogin.xaml.cs**

```
  public partial class UserLogin : ContentPage
  {
          // Here you get the MOBILE SCREEN HEIGHT && WIDTH
          int heightScreen=App.screenHeight;
          int widthScreen=App.screenHeight;

 public UserLogin()
     {
                       lblTitle.FontSize=height=Screen/36.8;
                     //The above value is equal to fontsize =20
                     imgProfile.HeightRequest=heightScreeen/10;
                     imgProfile. WidthRequest=heightScreeen/10;
            }
    }
```

**C# Design:**

```
 public class UserLogin: ContentPage
      {
          // Here you get the MOBILE SCREEN HEIGHT && WIDTH
          int heightScreen=App.screenHeight;
          int widthScreen=App.screenHeight;

          public UserLogin()
               {
                   Label lab = new Label()
                    {
                      FontSize = heightScreen/ 36.8
                      //the above value is equal to fontsize =20
                    };

                   Image imgProfile=new Image()
                    {
                         Source="Logo.png",
                         HeightRequest=heightScreeen/10,
                         WidthRequest=heightScreeen/10
                  }
          }
   }
```

This is another way but I thought it's not correct way

Comment: Is there any way that i can bind these fontsize values in xaml file directly?